# Evaluation of $\mathbb E[\int _{t_1} ^{t_2} f(s, X_s^{t,x} )ds \mid \mathcal F _{t_1} ]$ for a markovian SDE solution.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F , \mathbb P)$, a filtration $\mathbb F = (\mathcal F _t )_{t\geq 0}$ and $\mathbb F$-adapted brownian motion $W=(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$, consider   $X^{t,x}= (X_s ^{t,x})_{s\in [t,T]}$ the (markovian) solution of the following SDE

$$ X_s^{t,x}= x + \int _s ^T b(s,X_u ^{t,x})  du + \int _s ^T \sigma(s,X_u ^{t,x}) dW_u $$
 under the standard assumptions on $b, \sigma $ for existence and uniqueness of the strong solution.

Let $f: [t, T] \times \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R $ a bounded function. Can we say that $\mathbb E[\int _{t_1} ^{t_2} f(s, X_s^{t,x} )ds \mid  \mathcal F _{t_1} ]=0$  (with $t\leq t_1 \leq t_2 \leq T$)? If yes, how to show it ?

Comment: "What can we say about..." seems a typical example of not a real question.

Comment: I reformulate the question. See edition please.

Comment: Now there is a question. The answer is "Obviously no" (why should this be zero?).

Comment: @Paul I agree with Did. Simply consider a trivial example: Let $b=\sigma=0$, then $X_s^{t,x}=x$ and, obviously, the conditional expectation is constant, but not necessarily $0$.

Comment: What @saz says, or $f=1$.

Comment: You are totally right. There was a typo in a demonstration I was reading which implicated this result.This make me freak out. So I called a reality check here. Thanks